# Configuring Hy to run on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, hy

I'm trying to debug Hy code in Visual Studio Code. I have downloaded the [`hy-mode`](https://github.com/xuqinghan/vscode-hy) theme and it works great. There's only one problem. The `hy-mode` theme disables breakpoints.

I can add a breakpoint to my Hy code by switching to a totally unrelated language (like CoffeeScript) and then my Python debugger works. But I can't add breakpoints when I'm in `hy-mode`.

I debug code by writing a Python file that imports a Hy file. When I run the Python pdb debugger on the Python file, pdb debugs the Hy code just fine. But I can't add breakpoints to the Hy file when I'm have `hy-mode` active.

Is there a way to edit a Visual Studio Code theme so that to allow the insertion of breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. By adding `"hy"` to the `languageIds` list in the following files I can get Hy files to display breakpoints.

- `./ms-python.python-2019.8.30787/package.json`
- `ms-python.python-2019.8.30787/out/client/package.json`

```
        "debuggers": [
            {
                "type": "python",
                "label": "Python",
                "languages": [
                    "python"
                ],
                "enableBreakpointsFor": {
                    "languageIds": [
                        "python",
                        "html",
                        "jinja",
                        "hy"
                    ]
                },
```